# Ruby new code changes not showing on our web application

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

We have a Ruby web application we have successfully deployed on Heroku.
However we have made some changes on our codes on localhost and redployed on Heroku, but the new codes didn;t reflect on our web application online.

Can someone from Heroku support community help us?
Thanks alot

Emmanuel

Comment: Have you committed the changes and pushed them to heroku ?

Comment: We just tried it now and the changes are reflecting on the web now. Thanks alot

Comment: Cool, I posted it as an answer in case someone has a similar issue in the future :)

Comment: Thanks Viktor, you are so kind :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to commit the changes to the project and push them afterwards to Heroku:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Change foo"
git push heroku master
```

You can find more details in the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).